# Error extracting product items for Market Basket Analysis using regular expressions in R (StringR)

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, stringr, data-wrangling

| order_id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | The Ordinary - High-Adherence Silicone Primer - 30ml, The Ordinary - Natural Moisturizing Factors + HA 30ml |
| 2 | Sandal, Brown - 44 |
| 3 | Acetate - Square - Black - Transition - Sunglasses, Cartier - 8221 - Rim less - Green Double Shade - Sunglasses, Ray Ban - Aviator - Brown Double Shade - 3026 - Diamond Hard - Unbreakable lens, Burberry - 2A357 - Havana - Aviator - Sunglasses, Acetate - Square - Black - Transition - Sunglasses, Cartier - 8221 - Rim less - Green Double Shade - Sunglasses, Ray Ban - Aviator - Brown Double Shade - 3026 - Diamond Hard - Unbreakable lens, Burberry - 2A357 - Havana - Aviator - Sunglasses |
| 4 | NasGas Instant Geyser DG6L, NasGas Instant Geyser DG6L, NasGas Instant Geyser DG6L |
| 5 | Mpow Flame Solo Bluetooth Earbuds, Punchy Bass IPX7 Waterproof In Ear Wireless Earphones Bluetooth Headphones, USB-CFast ChargingBT5.028H Playtime Built-in Mic for Running Workout, Mpow Flame Solo Bluetooth Earbuds, Punchy Bass IPX7 Waterproof In Ear Wireless Earphones Bluetooth Headphones, USB-CFast ChargingBT5.028H Playtime Built-in Mic for Running Workout |

Above is a sample set of product items in the dataset. This is how the items are stored across the database.

Consider order id 3:
The first item is acetate... the second item Cartier... the third Burberry... and after that, the items just repeat twice and in some item cases (order id 4) repeat thrice. I need to remove this repetition. The delimiter, in this case, is the comma.

Secondly:

consider order id 4: Here i cannot separate the items on the basis of a comma as the first product item ends at Workout and has commas within one product item description

I was using the following code earlier

```
data.frame(tran_pay4) %>%
  mutate(product_name = str_extract_all(product_name, "((?!\\s)[^,]+)(?!.*\\1)"))
```

This resolves for most of the carts but it does not for case::order_id = 5
The objective is to keep individual product items.

The output should look like this:

| order_id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | The Ordinary - High-Adherence Silicone Primer - 30ml, The Ordinary - Natural Moisturizing Factors + HA 30ml |
| 2 | Sandal, Brown - 44 |
| 3 | Acetate - Square - Black - Transition - Sunglasses, Cartier - 8221 - Rim less - Green Double Shade - Sunglasses, Ray Ban - Aviator - Brown Double Shade - 3026 - Diamond Hard - Unbreakable lens, Burberry - 2A357 - Havana - Aviator - Sunglasses |
| 4 | NasGas Instant Geyser DG6L |
| 5 | Mpow Flame Solo Bluetooth Earbuds Punchy Bass IPX7 Waterproof In Ear Wireless Earphones Bluetooth Headphones USB-CFast ChargingBT5.028H Playtime Built-in Mic for Running Workout |

Please let me know how to go about this?

Comment: order_id= 1 is how i would want my itemsets to appear

Comment: Four things: please go through your post again and correct the typos there; e.g., "second item carrier" should be "second item `Cartier`". Second, post reproducible data. Third, say exactly what your objective is (this is missing!). Foruth, post expected output.

Comment: added the changes - please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need regular expression. You can simply use `strsplit` and `unique` to find unique items.

```
tran_pay4$newproduct = sapply(strsplit(tran_pay4$product_name, ", "), 
                              function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ", "))
```